# How to check selected date and selected time is less than current or greater than current date and time using angularjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, date

I have used datepicker  and timepicker i got some date time here i want to check that selected date and time is less than current date and time or gratter than current date and time.for example i have selected date var

```
Selected date = "Sat Dec 12 2015 ";
var Selected date ="Sat Dec 12 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)";
```

and selected time 11:00 AM ; `var selectedtime='11:00 AM'`
 how can i check selected date and time 11:00 AM is less than current date and time or gratter  than date and current time .i need to show alert i new to this technology help me out

```
$scope.date="Sat Dec 12 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)";
$scope.time = "11:00 AM";
   $scope.result = function () {
     var now = new Date();
     var nowTime = new Date((now.getMonth()+1) + "/" + now.getDate() + "/" + now.getFullYear() + " " + now.getHours()+":"+now.getMinutes());
     var userTime = new Date((now.getMonth()+1) + "/" + now.getDate() + "/" + now.getFullYear() + " " + $scope.time);
     if (nowTime.getTime() > userTime.getTime()) {
       return "passed";
     }else if (nowTime.getTime() == userTime.getTime()) {
       return "present";
     }else {
       return "future";
     }
   }
```

Expectation:For this particular date(Sat Dec 12 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)) that selected time is past or future i need to identify pls help me out

Comment: What exactly isn't working with the code you have? If you have two valid date objects, just comparing them the way you're doing should work fine? Note that `new Date(year, month, day ... etc)` is the correct syntax

Comment: for this date Sat Dec 12 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)  selected time 11:00 AM is past or future i need to find

Comment: pls update my fiddle

Comment: pls update your answer in jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

First of all the first part of the code is not valid javascript, but I assume it's an error you've already figured out.

Then you can just count the number of milliseconds. With that string you can come up with a date:

`var toCheck = new Date('Sat Dec 12 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)');`

now, all you need is the number of UNIX milliseconds in your current date and in that date:

`var msToCheck = toCheck.getTime();`

`var msNow = Date.now();`

now you just compare them!

`return msToCheck < msNow ? 'past' : 'future';`

I hope this was helpful